# ASP.NET MVC: Unit testing session variables does't change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, session, moq

I'm trying to unit test a Logout action of my controller. My controller recive an interface wich deals with session variables:

```
public HomeController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ISecurityService security = null) 
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;   

    if (security != null)
    {
        _securityService = security;
    }
    else
    {
        _userService = new UserService(_unitOfWork)
        _securityService = new SecurityService(_userService);    
    }
}
```

Using Moq, I create a HttpSessionStateBase object
Which I use to create a SecurityService object in my unit test class:

```
var mockSession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
mockSession.SetupGet(s => s["UserID"]).Returns("1");
HttpSessionStateBase session = mockSession.Object;
ISecurityService _securityService = new SecurityService(_userService, session);
```

My SecurityService

```
public class SecurityService : ISecurityService 
{
    private readonly IUsuarioService _userService ;
    private readonly HttpSessionStateBase _session;

    public int UserID
    {
        get { return Convert.ToInt32(_session["UserID"]); }
        set { _session["UserID"] = value; }
    }

    public SecurityService(IUserService service, HttpSessionStateBase session = null)
    {
        _userService = service;
        _session = session ?? new HttpSessionStateWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Session);
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        // I'm trying to delete this variable, but I can't
        _session["UserID"] = 0;
        _session.Clear();
        _session.Abandon();
    }
}
```

Finally, my test method

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Should_delete_session_variable_from_the_user()
    {
        controller.Logout();

        // It's allways 1
        Assert.IsTrue(Convert.ToInt32(session["UserID"]) == 0);
    }
```

---

When I debug this code, I can see that the session variable does not chage its value. But, if I open a "Quick Watch" window and execute `_session["UserID"] = 0;`, its value change.

I can't understand why. This is the first time that I see that a variable does not chage its value in debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found, the solution is to add an `SetupSet` method.
This is the final code:

```
int sessionValue = 0;
var mockSession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
mockSession.SetupSet(s => s["UserId"] = It.IsAny<int>())
    .Callback((string name, object val) => sessionValue = (int) val);
mockSession.SetupGet(s => s["UserId"]).Returns(() => sessionValue);
```